# Send google group chat invite to non-contacts

Tags: xmpp, strophe, google-talk, punjab

My requirement is that I need to send a google group chat invite to to people who are not in my contact list.
From my application I am able to create room on groupchat.google.com. I am able to invite people in my contact list to the chat room, but I am not able to invite google users who are not in my contact list to the chat room.

```
RECV: '<message to="mymail@gmail.com/88403C03" from="somemail@gmail.com" id="3331"
type="error"><x jid="private-chat-cc1e6f03-6f2b-44ca-8295-
fac4757f2899@groupchat.google.com" reason="This is testing invite" 
xmlns="jabber:x:conference"/><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable 
xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error>
</message>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Talk does not route messages to users which are not on your contact list for privacy reasons. This means it will work only with subscribed users on your contact list.